# How do I return a JSON response message and an HTTP error code from javax.servlet.filter doFilter method?

Tags: java, json, rest

I have created a servlet filter for our application that processes REST requests. I have annotated the web.xml and created my filter. The filter works well, but only returns a JSON text message. I need to also return a 405 HTTP status code. When I perform my tests, and one fails, I have a simple PrintWriter that prints the error message:

```
public class MyFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse apiResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        apiResponse.setContentType("application/json");
        htmlOut = apiResponse.getWriter();
        mainErrorObject = new JSONObject();
        if(true){
            htmlOut.println(mainErrorObject.toString());
        }
        htmlOut.close();
    }
}
```

So, like I said, how do I return both the JSON text message AND the HTTP error code?

Comment: `response.setStatus(405)`

Comment: Very cool ... thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ServletResponse` implements `HttpServletResponse` and it has a `setStatus` method, which sets the status code for the response.

> setStatus
>
> void setStatus(int sc)
>
> Sets the status code for this response. This method is used to set the return status code when there is no error (for example, for the status codes SC_OK or SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY). If there is an error, and the caller wishes to invoke an error-page defined in the web application, the sendError method should be used instead.
> The container clears the buffer and sets the Location header, preserving cookies and other headers.